# Why doesn't latex2html beautify quotes?

Tags: latex2html

Pushing the following through latex2html:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Why doesn't latex2html beautify ``quotes?''
\end{document}
```

for me produces html that includes

```
Why doesn't latex2html beautify ``quotes?''
```

It is fundamental to LaTeX to recognize single and double quotes and replace them with typographically pleasing versions -- this does happen of course with pdflatex acting on this input, why does latex2html drop the ball?

I checked the man page, is there a switch I'm missing?

Comment: I thought `latex2html` was kind of old and not particularly good (but I don't have it installed any more).  [tex4ht](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex4ht), is usually a better choice.  And then there's always [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).  Both of these convert the quotation marks to 'smart quotes' in your example.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with `latex2html` you can add the following to your `.latex2html-init` file:

```
sub do_cmd_textquotedblleft{ '&#x201C;' . $_[0]; }

sub do_cmd_textquotedblright{ '&#x201D;' . $_[0]; }

sub do_cmd_textquoteleft{ '&#x2018;' . $_[0]; }

sub do_cmd_textquoteright{ '&#x2019;' . $_[0]; }
```

Then in your document you can do something like:

```
\newcommand*{\dq}[1]{\textquotedblleft #1\textquotedblright}
```

and just do `\dq{quoted stuff}`.

---

**Aside:** I use either `tex4ht` or `latex2html`, depending on what I want to achieve. If I want the HTML version to be significantly different in appearance and I want to use Perl code to do stuff that's not required for the PDF versions, then I use `latex2html` otherwise I use `tex4ht`.